# How to create non-regular ticks for a JavaFx slider

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, slider, timeline

I want to set specific tick on my slider.
For exemple:

`[---¦---¦-----------¦------O-¦--]`

- `[-----]` : The slider
- `¦` : The tick
- `O` : The cursor

The purpose is to create a timeline where we can see the highlight.

Comment: Not supported by the standard FX slider. You'd have to create your own, or find a library with one.

Comment: You have several options, but the main two are, 1) You would need to create your own implementation of the slider that adds this functionality, or 2) You could place labels/buttons on top of the slider that look like your tick and you could use events to work out when the cursor is over the tick and perform your action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose your own widget to put the ticks up against a slider.  The only tricky bit is to make sure that you setPickOnBounds() to false for the slider.  Also putting the ticks into a VBox and then setPickOnBounds() to true for the VBox makes it easier to click on the ticks:

```
public class SliderSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static Image arrowImage = new Image("https://www.shareicon.net/data/12x12/2015/09/01/94166_arrow_512x512.png");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new SliderWithTicks(), 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class SliderWithTicks extends Pane {

        private Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 30);

        SliderWithTicks() {
            getChildren().addAll(new Tick(80), new Tick(20), new Tick(30), slider);
            slider.minWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
            slider.setPickOnBounds(false);
        }

        class Tick extends VBox {
            Tick(int value) {
                getChildren().add(new ImageView(arrowImage));
                setPickOnBounds(true);
                setOnMouseClicked(evt -> slider.adjustValue(value));
                translateXProperty().bind((slider.widthProperty().subtract(16)).multiply(value / slider.getMax()).add(2));
                translateYProperty().set(12);
            }
        }
    }
}
```